# Vertical grid with different cells in Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-gridlayout

There was a slightly interesting question: we need to make something like a vertical grid, without a fixed number of columns and clickable cells (available for selection) that adapt to the size of the text.
I show something approximate in the screenshot, but the length of the text in my case can be different, from 5 to 12 characters, and the cells need to be adapted to the length. It is also not known the number of these cells in advance, since the list with them will come from the backend.

[image]

Comment: Like a [flow layout](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/flow)?

Comment: @Slaw Looks good, thanks)
In fact, you need something similar to FlexBoxLayoutManager to implement